# Library libPocoCryptod.so.81 not found

Tags: poco-libraries

I'm getting the following error message when I run a program that uses Poco::NetSSL:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libPocoCryptod.so.81: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(PROJECT_NAME "pocotest")
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
find_package(Poco REQUIRED DataMySQL Net NetSSL)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/PocoTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Poco::Net Poco::NetSSL)
```

I installed Poco libraries from source, making sure to enable NetSSL. If I `ls /usr/local/lib`, the file *libPocoCrypto.so.81* is there. I don't know what's missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be linking with the **debug** version rather than the **release** version.  Your error is for the "d" version of the file, "libPocoCryptod.so.81".  But your file is the release version "libPocoCrypto.so.81"

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to run `sudo ldconfig` on Ubuntu.